# Replace property of a nested object by matching its key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an object of the following kind

```
let obj = {
    "p1" : "main",
    "p2" : {
        "p21" : [
            {
                "key1" : "val1",
                "value1" : "val2",
            },
            {
                "prop"  : "test",
                "value" : "dummy"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Need to find the "prop", and if its present set the "value" to empty string. Note there might be any number objects inside "p21" and in any order. Just need to find "prop" and then update "value" to empty string

Have tried the following

```
obj.p2.p21.map((item) => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("prop")) {
      item.value = "";
    }
})
```

Comment: Your code works (although you do not need to use `map`, a simple `forEach` is enough). If your problem is that the objects stored in `p21` do not have the same structure, the issue might be the creation of this object.

Comment: Same @Seblor, what is the error of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a function to check the key and then replace value.

```js
let obj = {
  "p1": "main",
  "p2": {
    "p21": [{
        "key1": "val1",
        "value1": "val2",
      },
      {
        "prop": "test",
        "value": "dummy"
      }
    ]
  }
}

function replaceValue(item) {
  for (var i in item) {
    if (i == "prop") {
      item["value"] = "";
      break;//break if you only want to place the first , otherwise remove it
    }
  }
}

obj.p2.p21.map(item => replaceValue(item));

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.p2.p21.map((elem) => {
    if(Object.keys(elem)[0] === "prop") 
        elem.value = ""
})
```

try something like that?

Comment: @Hongrac yes, but object values are serialized in the same order, there s no reason for it to change unless you change your models, in all the cases, the idea is here, worst case scenario, you can go through Object.keys(elem) with another map.